# Multiple currencies in commerce kickstart

Tags: commerce

How to make different prices for one product.I want to display product price in both currency that is euro/$ without any currency selector.

Answer (score 0):

[Commerce Multicurrency](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) may help you, see this [screencast](https://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-multicurrency) form Commerce Guys.